# Can't install DebugKit in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-debug-kit

I set up the DebugKit in cakephp but I'm getting this error:

> Error: DebugKit.ToolbarComponent could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class ToolbarComponent below in file:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\eperformance\app\Plugin\DebugKit\Controller\Component\ToolbarComponent.php

```
<?php class ToolbarComponent extends Component { } ?>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: check your bootstrap do you have CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); ?

Comment: What was the procedure for your installation?

Answer (score 1):

My ng case:
cakephp ver.2.6.4 and
debugkit ver.2.2 or master

My successful case:
cakephp ver.2.6.1 and
debugkit ver.2.2

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible walk through:

1. In bootstrap use this line `CakePlugin::load('DebugKit');` OR `CakePlugin::loadAll();`
2. Use this link to download debug kit [click here](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit)
3. Follow the  README.md file in above link